# Delphi 6 indy connection hanging

Tags: delphi, sockets, indy

I am having small issue. After I make a connection between the server and client. I would close the client, and then the server, but the server hangs and sends me a "program has crashed" I think the problem I am having is that the server doesn't recognize a client has disconnected, and still thinks the client is active. Here is the source code:

client:

```
unit client;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ScktComp, Winsock, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetIpFromDns(HostName: string): string;
type
  tAddr = array[0..100] of PInAddr;
  pAddr = ^tAddr;
var
  I: Integer;
  WSA: TWSAData;
  PHE: PHostEnt;
  P: pAddr;
begin
  Result := HostName;
  WSAStartUp($101, WSA);
  try
    PHE := GetHostByName(pChar(HostName));
    if (PHE <> nil) then
    begin
  P := pAddr(PHE^.h_addr_list);
  I := 0;
  while (P^[i] <> nil) do
  begin
  Result := (inet_nToa(P^[i]^));
  Inc(I);
  end;
    end;
  except
  end;
  WSACleanUp;
end;





procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
IdTCPClient1.Host := GetIpFromDns('example.no-ip.org');
IdTCPClient1.Port := 9000;
IdTCPClient1.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
if IdTCPclient1.Connected = True then
IdTCPClient1.Disconnect
else
end;

end.
```

Server:

```
unit server;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ScktComp, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPServer;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);



  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
showmessage('client connected');
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
showmessage('client disconnected');
end;



end.
```

it may not look like I set up a listening port for indy, but I did in the object inspector page. For some reason if I put IdTCPServer.DefaultPort and Active in the form create it throws more errors.

I also tried IdTCPClient1.DisconnectSocket but no luck there either.

Do I need to create something on the server side to check the connections periodically? if so, what would be best way to do that?

Comment: The method IdTCPServer1Connect is called in the context of the server thread. Use synchronize to execute it in the main VCL thread.

Comment: Does it work with localhost instead of GetIpFromDns('example.no-ip.org')?

Comment: To further clarify mjn's comment, `ShowMessage` is VCL code and not thread safe.

Comment: You don't need `GetIpFromDns()`. Set `Host` to `example.no-ip.org` and let `Connect()` resolve it for you. The only reason you should resolve manually is if the hostname has multiple IPs, in which case you should loop through each IP connecting to each one until successful. But if you only care about connecting to one IP, let Indy do the work for you.

Comment: Also, `TIdTCPServer` requires on `OnExecute` event handler assigned, or else the `Active` property setter will raise an exception when activating the server at runtime.